# Probability that an $m$ digit number does not contain $0$, $5$, $6$ nor $9$

Tags: probability

Given an $m$-digit number, what is the probability that it does not contain any of the following digits: $\{0, 5, 6, 9\}$?

Answer (score 1):

There are $10$ possible digits. The set of *disallowed* digits you defined contains $4$ of them. So the set of *allowed* digits contains $6$.

For a single digit, taken at random, the chance that it belongs to the allowed set is $6$ out of $10$, or a probability of $0.6$.

If you do this $m$ times, assuming each lottery is random and independent, the probability gets exponentiated. So the probability $p_{1}(m)$ of $m$ allowed digits is:

$$p_1(m)=0.6^m$$

However, as pointed out by Arthur in the comments, by most conventions, an $m$-digit number does not have a leading $0$. Therefore, for the leading number, the set of possible digits contains $9$ elements. Then, the chance of success is $6$ out of $9$. The final probability $p_{2}(m)$ for an $m$-digit number is:

$$p_2(m) = \frac{6}{9} \times \frac{6}{10}^{(m-1)}$$

Comment: There is some interference from the leading digit. Specifically, it can never be $0$, so there you really have $6$ out of $9$ digits which are valid.

Comment: @Arthur Nice! Very true, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a similar question

answer is

Total no. of m digit numbers=10^m
If 0,5,6 and 9 can't be used, total no. of m digit numbers=6^m
Hence,
Probability=(6^m/10^m)=0.6^m

Answer (score 0):

A number with m digits.

$p=\frac{\text{# }favorable\;outcomes}{\text{# }total\;outcomes}=\frac{6\times6\times...\times6}{9\times10\times...\times10}=\frac{6^m}{9\times10^{m-1}}$

The favorable outcomes have no $0,5,6,9$ for each digit, which means the possible outcomes for each digit is $10-4=6$. Since there are m digits, the number of favorable outcomes $6\times6\times...\times6=6^m$

About the number of total outcomes, each digit has 10 possible outcomes {0,1,...9} except for the leading digit (9 possible outcomes), the number of total outcomes $9\times10\times10\times...\times10=9\times10^{m-1}$